# CHARINDEX on SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql

I have a column in a table with sample data as follows:

```
ServiceTypeIDs
1,9
4
```

In my Where clause I use the following to search on it:

```
   WHERE
( @ServiceTypes is null or       
   charindex(','+cast(SEP.ServiceTypeIDs as varchar(255))+',',      
   ','+@ServiceTypes+',') > 0)))
```

If my param `@ServieTypes` equals `'1,9'`, then I get results, but when it's `@ServiceTypes = '1'` or just `'9'`, then I don't recieve anything back. I'm stuck and tried the above.

```
exact column looks like below

7
8
2
5
4
7
7
7
7
7
7
1
7
null
6,7
7
6
1
7
null
7
7
7
7
7
8
7
6
1
1
1
6
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
7
1
7
7
1
7
8
7
1
1
2
1
null
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
8
6
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
1
7
7
1
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
1
1
1
1
1,2
1
1
1,2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1,2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
6
7
7
1
8
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
2
7
null
null
1
1
1
1
1
7
7
7
1,2
6
7
1
2
1
1
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
5
5
1
1
1
7
7
7
1
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
7
3
1
9
9
9
9
null
9
1,2
9
9
9
8,9
1,9
1,9
1,9
2,9
1,9
1,9
1,9
1,8
1,9
1,9
9
9
9
9
5
4
3
1
null
1,2,3
6
9
9
9
8,9
9
9
9
1,9
```

Comment: We know you need help that's why your posting here.. please don't write titles like this

Comment: It looks like you are trying to store multiple ServiceTypeIDs in one coulmn. _Don't._ Use a JOIN table. The exact use isn't clear, mustr depend on columns you don't show us here. But, basically, it looks like you are using some sort of text concatenation as a replacement for a normalized schema. I repeat, don't.

Answer (score 1):

Your arguments to [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) are reversed. Use this instead:

```
CHARINDEX(','+@ServiceTypes+',', ','+CAST(SEP.ServiceTypeIDs AS VARCHAR(255))+',') > 0
```

It should be noted that your actual problem is a poor database design. You should never store lists as strings like that, use a separate table instead, with one row per association.

Comment: Exactly... Also, do you really need to be casting the column to varchar?

Comment: well if i pass '9' it works but if i just pass '1' then it does not work.

Comment: Any change you have a space before the `1` (like in `[space]1,9`) on the table? Try `LTRIM`.